# How to unit test the logic in the onDestory() with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Let's say I have to remove listener in the `onDestory`:

```
fun onDestory(){
  ...
  listener = null
}
```

When I tried to test it:

```
activityScenario.moveToState(DESTORYED)
activityScenario.onActivity {activity ->
  assertNull(activity.listener)
}
```

All I got is an error: `"Cannot run onActivity since Activity has been destroyed already"`

So how to test the logic inside onDestroy()?